# Taxonomy-$taxonomy-$term not working

Tags: theme-development, template-hierarchy

This question might seem very simple, but I cannot find a proper answer for it. 
In my example I should have multiple pages that should display 'FAQ'. For that I have added custom taxonomy `page_type` to default `page` post type and set 'FAQ' as `page_type` for those pages. 
Now, according to documentation :

> taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php - If the taxonomy were sometax, and taxonomy's term were someterm WordPress would look for taxonomy-sometax-someterm.php. In the case of Post Formats, the taxonomy is 'post_format' and the terms are 'post_format-{format}. i.e. taxonomy-post_format-post-format-link.php

In my case, I add `taxonomy-page_type_faq.php` template file, but wordpress keeps using the default `page.php`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `taxonomy-$taxonomy-$term.php` template is a template for an archive, a listing. It's not a template for a post, be it a post of type page, or anything else. It overrides `taxonomy-$taxonomy.php`, then `taxonomy.php`, then `archive.php` followed by `index.php`

Comment: Well, as I understood, I can't use it for `single` pages?

Comment: You can give a page a custom taxonomy yes, but custom taxonomy templates are for showing taxonomy archives, aka listing posts and pages, not the page itself. E.g. tag archives, category archives, etc. If you're trying to re-implement post formats or page templates, taxonomies won't do that for you. You can use them to store and pick which template is used, but you then have to write the code that actually loads the template based off of that data